# Tagging translated text correctly (tagging with lang="")

Tags: html, xhtml, translation

A client has asked me to add some polish text to their website, not having much experience in this area, can anyone tell me which of the two 'lang' solutions below is correct (or offer an alternative):-

Tag everything:-

```
<div lang="pl"> 
<h2 lang="pl">Najlepszy ruch jaki zrobisz!</h2>

<p lang="pl">Do przyszłych najemców:</p>

<p lang="pl">Tutaj w SPS mamy bogate doświadczenie na rynku najmu i wyszukiwaniu domu, który będzie idealnym miejscem dla przyszłych lokatorów. Dla wielu może to być trudne i stresujące, dlatego my w SPS pomożemy Wam przejść przez pole minowe związane z najmem i uczynić ten proces  najprostszym i najszybszym jak to możliwe.</p>

<p lang="pl">Jeśli szukasz nieruchomości obecnie lub w najbliższej przyszłości  prosimy o kontakt z naszym doświadczonym , przyjaznym i pomocnym personelem, a my  postaramy się pomóc  znaleźć Ci idealne miejsce, które jest właśnie dla Ciebie.</p>

<p lang="pl">Więc aby w łatwy sposób wynająć zadzwoń już dziś.</p>
</div>
```

Just tag the div

```
<div lang="pl"> 
<h2>Najlepszy ruch jaki zrobisz!</h2>

<p>Do przyszłych najemców:</p>

<p>Tutaj w SPS mamy bogate doświadczenie na rynku najmu i wyszukiwaniu domu, który będzie idealnym miejscem dla przyszłych lokatorów. Dla wielu może to być trudne i stresujące, dlatego my w SPS pomożemy Wam przejść przez pole minowe związane z najmem i uczynić ten proces  najprostszym i najszybszym jak to możliwe.</p>

<p>Jeśli szukasz nieruchomości obecnie lub w najbliższej przyszłości  prosimy o kontakt z naszym doświadczonym , przyjaznym i pomocnym personelem, a my  postaramy się pomóc  znaleźć Ci idealne miejsce, które jest właśnie dla Ciebie.</p>

<p>Więc aby w łatwy sposób wynająć zadzwoń już dziś.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latter. You only need to indicate *changes* in language.

Otherwise you would end up with:

```
<html lang="en-us">
    <head lang="en-us">
        <title lang="en-us"> A document written in American English </title>
…
```